# if not empty bloginfo('description')

Tags: bloginfo

Can someone tell, how to check whether it's empty?

```
<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
```

Something like:

```
<?php if (!empty bloginfo('description');) ?>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ) {
    //do something
}
```

bloginfo echoes the description, get_bloginfo returns php variable

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work to me.

Comment: This works:
`<?php if(get_bloginfo('description') <> '') { ?>
    // do something
<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Ptriek's example checks if the value is true and unfortunately an empty value still evaluates to true, hence why it doesn't work as expected. Try the following instead..

```
<?php if( !empty( get_bloginfo('description') ) : ?>

<!-- your html -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

**NOTE:** An empty check will also ring true for empty strings, so covers exactly the same case as the code you posted in the comment on ptriek's answer..